# Kubernetes running nginx doesn't start

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am running a 5 nodes Kubernetes cluster. I'm trying to run a (on nginx based) container.

The dockerfile is straight forward:

```
FROM nginx
COPY src/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

the html is in the `src` folder. When I try to run it with Docker everything is fine. 
I now try to run it in Kubernetes with this yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: three-tier
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-end
  namespace: three-tier
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: front-end
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front-end
        image: xanvier/angularfrontend #TBD
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8079
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
          capabilities:
            drop:
              - all
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-end
  labels:
    name: front-end
  namespace: three-tier
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8079 #nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    name: front-end
---
```

In the ui I get this error message:
[image: Docker emerg messages]
And in the logs of Docker this arises:

[image: Kubernetes dashboard error]

I thought I did something very simple, so I probably looking straight at it but can't see the problem.

I alse tried to give the folder `/var/cache/nginx` 777 rights. to add `RUN chmod 777 /var/cache/nginx -R` to the dockerfile. Also I tried to disable caching to add a new config file which disables caching altogether. Both didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is awkward...

```
    securityContext:
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 10001
      capabilities:
        drop:
          - all
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Removed those lines and worked like a charm